# neo4j 3.4 - Can't add spatial point in node creation (Current record format does not support POINT_PROPERTIES.)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just upgraded a docker container to Neo4j 3.4, excited to start using some of its new features, most importantly their native support for spatial data.

I tried running a test query to create an example node with a `point` like so:

```
CREATE (n:LocationNode { name: 'New York', location: point({latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0}) })
```

The result was an exception thrown which reads as follows:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: Current record format does not support POINT_PROPERTIES. Please upgrade your store to the format that support requested capability.
```

I am unaware of any configuration required to add support for spatial data. Is there anything I need to configure or enable to support `point` properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would also have worked if you set `allow_store_upgrade=true` before starting Neo4j 3.4 on an older store. Neo4j can run with older store formats without requiring an upgrade, but in that case you will also not get the features of the new formats (like support for Point and DateTime as property types).

Note that this does not also cover index formats, so even if you `allow_store_upgrade=true`, pre-existing indexes might not support the newer features (like native indexes for strings, datetime and point). If you also want to upgrade the indexes to get the newer features, drop and recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a new store by backing up the old data, deleting the old `graph.db` store from the previous version and creating a new one.

Classic me, trying to fix something for hours, finally deciding to place a question here, only to find a solution minutes later.